# Expressing $\log[(2n)!]-\log[n!]-\log[(n+1)!]$ via Stirling's formula and Taylor series

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion, catalan-numbers

Need explanation on the solution below:

Stirlings Formula: $$n! = \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac n e\right)^n\left(1+\frac {1}{12n} + \frac{1}{288n^2}- \frac{1}{51840n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$

We have the formula:

$$\log(C_n)=\log[(2n)!]-\log[n!]-\log[(n+1)!] $$

The author proceed to use Stirling three times and with Taylor series to the above equation to get:
$$\log(C_n)=n \log (4)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left({\pi  n^3}\right)-\frac{9}{8 n}+\frac{1}{2
   n^2}-\frac{21}{64 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Could anyone explain how the author came to this solution for $\log(C_n)$ ?

Comment: It looks like a tedious process of using enough terms of the expansion.